# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute (python) (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm copying email every 10 minutes from https://10minutemail.pl/ and I want to paste it to `email_elem` element on another web site, using code below:

```
driver.get("https://10minutemail.pl/")
email2_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]").text
time.sleep(2)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
time.sleep(2)
email_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='emailOrPhone']")
email_elem.clear()
email_elem.send_keys(email_elem.email2_elem)
```

Bu I get error:

> AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'email2_elem'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
email_elem.send_keys(email_elem.email2_elem)
```

, and it is exactly what it says - you have stored that text inside the (standalone) variable `email2_elem`, but are referencing it as if it is an attribute of another one, `email_elem` - which it is not.
Just change it to:

```
email_elem.send_keys(email2_elem)
```

, and it will work.

Comment: I have 1 more problem when i try to paste it later code worka normaly but nothing appears. But when i copy other text with same method from somewhere else it works. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "paste it later" and "copy other text"? Copy and paste are clipboard operations, while your code sample doesn't use it, it just gets a text and stores it in a variable.

Comment: I mean. When i try to get this email from 10 minutes mail and use it as shown. It's just doesn't appear

Comment: Ok, that's a different question, but still - it's either the xpath is not targeting the correct element, or - most likely, it's because you are trying to get the text of an `<input>` tag. As you, I presume, want to get the value that is where there, using `text()` is not the way to do it - you need to change that to `.getAttribute("value")`